# Save Related Documents In Mongo Reactive But Not In The Same Collection

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-webflux, reactive

I would like to know, how to save related documents in reactive mongo ?. Because I find a code that attempts to do the magic... But when it should save the related document in another collection, it serializes inside the "father" of the relationship let say... I know that in spring data reactive mongo, @DbRef doesnt have support... How could I save the data in a way that, if I query the collection, I see that the attributesare the name of the collection and the generated id instead all of the object attributes ?.

[image]

If the pic above is seen, you will see that the attribute "user" is saved as a nested document but not in the corresponding collection. Do I need to hook in another event ?.

Comment: Please don't paste images, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266

Comment: To save related documents in different collections atomically, you need two different _insert_ operations - perhaps within a _transaction_.

Answer (score 0):

I had put a listener onbeforeconvert to scan every time a save operation is to be applied and save the object... How to proceed ?... think I should verify if it has a related doc from another collection and if its nonnull... If the object doesnt have any attr l
Alike, then save it... if not continue the scanning... dunno